# Impossible to load dataset [dataset name] due to the following service errors: Method not supported in All-In-One SpagoBI 5.1

Tags: spagobi

I am creating cockpit in SpagoBI 5.1. But, it through a error like:-

"Impossible to load dataset [dataset name] due to the following service errors:
Method not supported;"

Why it is occurred?

Please let me know the solution, if anybody knows.

Thanks
Aman

Comment: I am getting the same error: 
An unexpected error occured while executing dataset: Impossible to read resultset did you find any solution for it .. I am trying to upload the Excel or csv sheet to the dataset ..